# Value not stored in file <Perl>

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. My motive is to read some value from a txt file and use it in my perl script.

The text file is something like this ::

```
Servers ::              
   (local)

      Tomas-Server1

      Tomas-Server2
      .........**
```

What i need to do is to get the 3rd line value (Tomas-Server2) and use it in my perl script. basically its calling the 3rd value to the perl script.

I have written a basic code for it ::

```
my($ServName1,$ServName,$ServName3) = getservername($servername);
my ($filenam) = 'data.txt';
my @Param = ();

open(INFILE,"<$filenam") or die "Couldn't open $filenam for reading\n";
while(<INFILE>) {
    chop($_); 
    push(@Param,$_);
}
close(INFILE);
return @Param;
}
```

But when i try to use the "$ServName2" value , it does not return anything. I guess the value contained should be "(local)" for it.

Comment: I think you forgot to include a `sub getservername {` line somewhere after the first line and before `my @Param = ();`.

Comment: That's not the 3rd line. That is the 7th line. Is that information really necessary? It seems you are not asking how to parse the file.

Comment: You should include `use strict;` at the top of all your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few problems with you example data, but I think I understand what you are trying to do. Assuming that you want the third server value (and not just line #3) you would probably want to have code that looks something like this...

```
#!perl

#some includes
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

#set some vars
my $TargetFileName="data_file.txt";
my $TargetServerNumber=3;

#call the sub
my @ServerArray=GetServerName($TargetFileName);

#did we get anything back?
if(@ServerArray) {
    #yep, we got some content
    print "Server number ".$TargetServerNumber."/".($#ServerArray+1)." is \"".$ServerArray[$TargetServerNumber-1]."\"\n"; #array numbers are 0-based
} else {
    #nope, we read the file but didn't any matching content
    print "No servers found in file \"".$TargetFileName."\".\n";
} #end if

print "\n";
print "Here's what was loaded into \@ServerArray...\n";
print Data::Dumper::Dumper(@ServerArray); #so you can see the full content of @ServerArray
print "All Done\n";
exit;

#----- subs go here -----

sub GetServerName {
    my $DataFileName=shift; #pull in the first arg - this alters @_ for the rest of the sub, so take care when doing this
    my @ReturnArray;
    #do some QA
    if(!$DataFileName) {die "You need to provide a file name to use this sub.\n"} #do we have a file name?
    if(!stat($DataFileName)) {die "The requested file name of \"".$DataFileName."\" does not exist.\n";} #does the file exist?
    open(INFILE, "<".$DataFileName) or die "Unable to open \"".$DataFileName."\" - ".$!;

    #ok, read the file content
    while(my $Line=<INFILE>) {
        chop($Line);
        $Line=~s/^\s+//g; #remove leading white spaces
        $Line=~s/\s+$//g; #remove trailing white spaces
        if(!$Line) {next;} #blank line, skip it

        #check for the headers
        if($Line=~m/^Servers/) {next;} #skip lines beginning with "Servers"
        if($Line=~m/^\(local\)/) {next;} #skip lines beginning with "(local)"

        #if we get here, we must want the line content, so add it to the array
        push(@ReturnArray, $Line);
    } #end while
    close(INFILE);

    #send the array data back, if any
    return @ReturnArray
} #end GetServerName sub

__END__

stuff below here does not need to be commented
```

I admit this is not the best way to approach the problem, but like most Perl hacks, it works. You'll notice the code is a bit overkill and does validation checks before passing data to some operations - get into the habit of doing this in any language you work in. This will help you return more meaningful errors when things go wrong and will also catch data related problems. The sample code also does a bit of data cleanup because leading and trailing will likely cause you problems later on. Blank lines (after cleaning) are also removed.

BTW, the data file I used as an example look like this...

```
Servers ::              
   (local)

      Tomas-Server1 
      Tomas-Server2  

      Tomas-Server3
      Tomas-Server4

      Tomas-Server5

      Tomas-ServerLast
```

Answer (score 1):

You never define a `$ServName2` variable.  The variable between `$ServName1` and `$ServName3` is just named `$ServName`, with no number.